# Entering a date array on a sheet converts to American format

Tags: excel, vba, date-format

I have an array of dates in VBA. If I print it to the sheet one date at a time everything is perfect. However, when I print the entire array to a column in bulk, the date format changes from (dd/mm/yy) to (mm/dd/yy). So May 7th is converted to July 5th and May 25th is not formatted as date on the sheet.

Here is my code.

(Another smaller problem: how can I get rid of the need to transpose when printing to a column? This piece of "pseudo code" is executed 30K times.)

```
Public Sub test05()
Dim dt As Date, fromDate As Date, toDate As Date
Dim dayCounter As Integer
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim dtArr() As Date
Set sheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
fromDate = DateSerial(2018, 8, 6)
toDate = DateSerial(2023, 8, 5)
sheet.Cells.ClearContents
dayCounter = 0
For dt = fromDate To toDate
    wd = Weekday(dt)
    If wd = 1 Or wd = 7 Then
        'skip weekends
        GoTo NextDayIteration
    End If
    dayCounter = dayCounter + 1

    ReDim Preserve dtArr(1 To dayCounter)

    dtArr(dayCounter) = dt

    'print the dates (one by one) to the sheet in column 1
    sheet.Cells(dayCounter, 1).Value2 = dt
NextDayIteration:
Next 'end of each day

'print all the dates array to the sheet in bulk, in column 2
Dim rng As Range
With sheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(UBound(dtArr) - LBound(dtArr) + 1, 2))
End With

rng.Value2 = Application.Transpose(dtArr)

End Sub
```

Comment: Paste `rng.Numberformat = "dd/mm/yy"` before `rng.Value2 =...` Now try it

Comment: If they are still interpreted as dates, I would recommend simply setting the numberformat of the range to the desired one.

Comment: I did it and it didn't help. It's not that the date is just presented wrong, the actual date is changed (from May 7th to July 5th). It's a more inherent problem than formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Transpose` or `Preserve`. You can do something like this instead:

```
Public Sub test05()
Dim dt As Date, fromDate As Date, toDate As Date
Dim dayCounter As Long
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim dtArr() As Date
Set sheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
fromDate = DateSerial(2018, 8, 6)
toDate = DateSerial(2023, 8, 5)
ReDim dtArr(1 To toDate - fromDate + 1, 1 To 1)
sheet.Cells.ClearContents
dayCounter = 0
For dt = fromDate To toDate
    wd = Weekday(dt)
    Select Case wd
    Case 1, 7
        'skip weekends
    Case Else
    dayCounter = dayCounter + 1

    dtArr(dayCounter, 1) = dt

    'print the dates (one by one) to the sheet in column 1
    sheet.Cells(dayCounter, 1).Value2 = dt
    End Select
Next 'end of each day

'print all the dates array to the sheet in bulk, in column 2
Dim rng As Range
With sheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(dayCounter, 2))
End With

rng.Value2 = dtArr

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this idea. The problem I had was that I can't be really sure how many elements will be in the array. Since I'm skipping weekends, the number of elements is actually smaller than (fromDate - toDate)

Comment: Did you try the code at all? It only outputs the correct number of rows based on the `dayCounter` variables.